# Spring Security in test and production environments

Tags: maven, spring-security, integration-testing

I would like to run Spring Security in two environments, a test environment and a production environment.

I tried having a configuration for the production environment:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.security" })
@Import({ WebSecurityInitializer.class })
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

And one for the integration test environment:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.security" })
@Import({ WebSecurityInitializer.class })
public class WebSecurityTestConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("stephane").password("mypassword").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

}
```

These two classes sit in different sources, one in src/main/java and one in src/test/java but they have the same package name.

The Maven build gives me the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique. Order of 100 was already used, so it cannot be used on com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.config.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2d511ca8@536972 too.
```

Is it that extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter twice is the reason the attempt at instantiating WebSecurityConfiguration again fails ?

How to go about it then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve the issue by adding a @Order(2) to the production environment WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and a @Order(1) to the test environment one.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.security" })
@Import({ WebSecurityInitializer.class })
@Order(2)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.security" })
@Import({ WebSecurityInitializer.class })
@Order(1)
public class WebSecurityTestConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

EDIT: A better solution was to avoid the use of the @Order annotation which in itself is a sign of messy configuration.

The issue was due to the loading of both WebSecurityConfiguration and WebSecurityTestConfiguration when running tests, when only one of them, the WebSecurityTestConfiguration was needed to be loaded.

With the help of a conditional annotation, it was then easy to only load the required one.

Here is the interface of the condition definition:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Conditional(EnvNotTestCondition.class)
public @interface EnvNotTest {
}
```

And here is its implementation:

```
public class EnvNotTestCondition implements Condition {

  private static final String ENV_TEST = "test";

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return context.getEnvironment().getProperty("env") == null || !context.getEnvironment().getProperty("env").equals(ENV_TEST);
    }

}
```